# Statistics, joint probability mass functions

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function

I have a question that has a village of 60 people. 16 are children, 20 are adults and 24 are elderly. 12 people are randomly selected, where X = children and Y = adults.

For part A, I have to work put p(X=6,Y=4) and for part B, I have to find an expression for the probabiltiy mass functions.

On part A) I have tried to find f(x,y) but don't know how to go about doing so. Another idea was permutations but I'm unsure if that's the right way of going about it. Any advice on how to get to an answer for part A? The rest of the question seems straightforward so this is the only bit I'm struggling with.

Comment: How many ways can you choose $12$ people?  How many ways can you choose $6$ children, $4$ adults, and $2$ elderly citizens?

Comment: Ok so I'd do (16C6*20C4*24C2)/60C12. Have I made a mathemtical error?

Comment: Nope, that looks good.